# How to create a file of the exact size of a directory (and its files), to hold a FAT32 filesystem?

Tags: linux, uefi, fat32

I'm trying to create a file with the minimum-enough size to contain a FAT32 filesystem, which, in turn, mirrors the contents of a directory (an ESP structure). This is needed to create an UEFI-bootable ISO image.

I've managed to create the file successfully (the ISO image boots), but I've had to create it with a fixed size, and not the actual size of its contents.

Here's what I have done to achieve it:

```
BOOT_IMG_DATA=$(mktemp -d)
BOOT_IMG=$ISO_DIR/boot/efi.img

mkdir -p $(dirname $BOOT_IMG)

truncate -s 4M $BOOT_IMG
mkfs.vfat $BOOT_IMG
mount $BOOT_IMG $BOOT_IMG_DATA
mkdir -p $BOOT_IMG_DATA/efi/boot

grub-mkimage \
    -C xz \
    -O x86_64-efi \
    -p /boot/grub \
    -o $BOOT_IMG_DATA/efi/boot/bootx64.efi \
    boot linux search normal configfile \
    part_gpt btrfs fat iso9660 loopback \
    test keystatus gfxmenu regexp probe \
    efi_gop efi_uga all_video gfxterm font \
    echo read ls cat png jpeg halt reboot

umount $BOOT_IMG_DATA
```

That code is part of a script that generates an UEFI-bootable ISO image. The whole script is here: https://github.com/Nitrux/mkiso/blob/master/mkiso#L79-L100.

I need a way to create a file that will contain the ESP structure with the exact size to hold both the ESP data (directories and files) and the FAT32 metadada. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You mean like `mkfs.vfat -C /path/to/image_to_create.img size` where you specify the `size` you want for the image? You can then `mount` the image and copy the files to it as needed. You can do the same thing with `dd` and then call `mkfs.vfat` on the image itself.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, what I need is the `size` parameter, in that case.

Comment: I would make a disk image, then shrink it after for archival.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right tool for this task is `du`.

```
mkfs.vfat -C $BOOT_IMG \
    $(( ($(stat -c %s $BOOT_IMG_DATA) / 1024 + 511) / 1024 ))
```

That command will create the file `$BOOT_IMG`, which will have enough size to keep the contents of `$BOOT_IMG_DATA`.